# INNER JOIN de tabelas não aparece os valores das suas colunas

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um **INNER JOIN** que faça a junção das colunas:

- `cd_devolucao` da tabela `devolucao`
- `cd_itens_venda` da tabela `itens_venda`
- `cd_produto` da tabela `produto`
- `valor_total` da tabela `itens_venda`

Estou querendo fazendo o `INNER JOIN` dessas colunas na tabela `itens_devolucao` reunindo as outras que possuem chaves estrangeiras dentro da tabela `itens_devolucao`. Só que **estão retornando todas elas vazias**.

O erro é que **quando é inserido um cadastro na tabela `itens_devolucao` o INNER JOIN funciona, só que eu queria que o INNER JOIN funcionasse mesmo com a tabela vazia** pois eu preciso usar requisição de dados em JSON.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT devolucao.cd_devolucao, itens_venda.cd_itens_venda, 
produto.cd_produto, itens_venda.valor_total FROM itens_devolucao
INNER JOIN devolucao ON (devolucao.cd_devolucao = itens_devolucao.cd_devolucao)
INNER JOIN itens_venda ON (itens_venda.cd_itens_venda = itens_devolucao.cd_itens_venda)
INNER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = itens_devolucao.cd_produto);
```

Comment: E sua tabela `itens_devolucao` está vazia? A definição das chaves estrangeiras está correta? Poste a definição das tabelas envolvidas e não apenas o desenho.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/3774)

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua ideia. Se não existir um registro `itens_devolucao` você quer retornar o produto cartesiano das demais tabelas?

Comment: @anonimo exatamente isso, mesmo não havendo registro de ```itens_devolucao``` eu quero que retorne o INNER JOIN das demais tabelas.

Comment: @Vorbbel: é melhor você rever o conceito de INNER JOIN.

Comment: Veja se é isto o que deseja: `FROM itens_devolucao
RIGHT OUTER JOIN devolucao ON (devolucao.cd_devolucao = itens_devolucao.cd_devolucao)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN itens_venda ON (itens_venda.cd_itens_venda = itens_devolucao.cd_itens_venda)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = itens_devolucao.cd_produto)`

Comment: @anonimo só retornou o registro de ```cd_produto```, pois eu apagei o registro de ```itens_devolucao``` que só havia um.

Comment: Eu não consegui entender o que você pretende mas o produto cartesiano de suas tabelas você consegue com: `SELECT devolucao.cd_devolucao, itens_venda.cd_itens_venda, 
produto.cd_produto, itens_venda.valor_total 
FROM itens_devolucao, devolucao, itens_venda, produto;`

Comment: @anonimo desse jeito que vc falou agora percebo o quão desnecessário foi o uso do INNER JOIN nesse código, eu não havia percebido isso.

Comment: Mas ainda não retorna os registros das colunas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo não usar as aspas no **ON** do **SELECT**, e quando você relaciona todas as tabelas de uma vez e não encontra o resultado provavelmente você não tem nenhum item que se encontra em todas as tabelas, porque nem todas as vendas possuem devolução por exemplo, nesse caso utilizaria o **LEFT JOIN** que, caso não exista o valor de determinada tabela trás como fosse **NULL** e não exclue o resultado da pesquisa:

```
SELECT devolucao.cd_devolucao, itens_venda.cd_itens_venda, 
produto.cd_produto, itens_venda.valor_total 
FROM itens_devolucao
LEFT JOIN devolucao 
  ON devolucao.cd_devolucao = itens_devolucao.cd_devolucao
LEFT JOIN itens_venda 
  ON itens_venda.cd_itens_venda = itens_devolucao.cd_itens_venda
LEFT JOIN produto 
  ON produto.cd_produto = itens_devolucao.cd_produto;
```

A sua consulta vai trazer todos os itens que foram devolvidos e todas as informações que constam em outras tabelas caso exista, caso queira buscar todos os produtos com suas respectivas "movimentações" utilize a tabela produto na **FROM** ou utilize o conceito de **OUTER JOIN**.

Comment: Ainda não retornou nada.

Comment: Descobrir o erro, quando ocorre uma inserção na tabela itens_venda o INNER JOIN funciona retornando todas as colunas com os registros.

Comment: Mais eu não queria isso, eu queria que o INNER JOIN funcionasse mesmo com a tabela ```itens_venda``` vazia.

Comment: Você pode definir as condições atraves do WHERE, mesmo tudo sendo atraves do LEFT JOIN, por exemplo: WHERE itens_venda.cd_itens_venda IS NOT NULL

Comment: @Vorbbel: é melhor você rever o conceito de INNER JOIN.